# CurveTo and ContinueCurveTo not drawing properly

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, ngraphics

I am using NGraphics and I want to generate a smooth curve.

Android devices are showing a different result, compared to iPhone when using the code below.

The line with surrounded by asterisks (*), if used on Android (tested on Samsung Galaxy S4) the curve looks as expected. However, on iPhone it doesn't look correct.

```
private bool DrawingMove(TouchData touchData)
{
    if (touchData == null)
    {
        Invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var stroke in _localStroke)
    {
        if (stroke.Pointer == touchData.PointerId)
        {
            var newPoint = ConvertLocalToGlobal(touchData.Point);
            var point = new PointModel();
            point.X = newPoint.X;
            point.Y = newPoint.Y;

            stroke.Points.Add(point);

            var length = stroke.Points.Count - 1;

            if (stroke.Points.Count >= 3)
            {
                var p1 = ConvertGlobalToLocal(
                    new Point(stroke.Points[length - 2].X,
                              stroke.Points[length - 2].Y));
                var p2 = ConvertGlobalToLocal(
                    new Point(stroke.Points[length - 1].X, 
                              stroke.Points[length - 1].Y));
                var p3 = ConvertGlobalToLocal(
                    new Point(stroke.Points[length].X, 
                              stroke.Points[length].Y));

                if (stroke.Points.Count == 3)
                {
                    stroke.Path.MoveTo(p1);
                    stroke.Path.CurveTo(p1, p2, p3);
                }
                else if (stroke.Points.Count > 3)
                {
                    **stroke.Path.LineTo(p2);**
                    stroke.Path.ContinueCurveTo(p2, p3);

                    Console.WriteLine("Path.ContinueCurveTo(new Point(" + p2.X + "," + p2.Y + "),new Point(" + p3.X + "," + p3.Y + "));");
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    return base.TouchesMoved(touchData);
}
```

The code above generates the following results:

**iPhone**
[image: iPhone Screenshot]

**Android**
[image: Android Screenshot]

I've also tried to reproduce this in small samples without all the touch drawing code above, simply by passing in coordinates to `CurveTo` and `ContinueCurveTo`, which yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... Just realised I have to pass in the current point plus the previous point and get the middle point.